# Continuous complex function without antiderivative

Tags: complex-analysis

It's a well-known result that every real continuos function has an antiderivative. Is this theorem still true for a complex function? If not, can someone point out a counter-example (and proof that it is indeed a counter-example)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The result is false for complex functions. If a complex function of a complex variable is differentiable, then it is analytic. In particular, if $F$ is holomorphic, so is $F'$. If $f$ is continuous but not differentiable, then it has no primitive.

Comment: Pefectly clear. Thank you!

Comment: I'm surprised that this answer mentions no particular example.

Comment: surprised in a bad way? i'm open for examples if you want to provide one! :)

Answer (score 5):

The modulus function, $f(z) = |z|$, is continuous but not complex-differentiable.

Suppose it had an antiderivative $F$, so that $F'(z) = f(z)$. Then $F$ would be infinitely differentiable (because all complex-analytic functions on $C$ are), which would make $f$ differentiable.

Why is $f$ not complex-differentiable?

Write $f(z) = u(z) + i v(z)$; then $v$ is the constant function $0$. Then if $f$ were analytic, the Cauchy-Riemann equations would tell you that the derivative of $u$ wrt the real and imaginary parts of $z$ are both $0$; thus $u$ is a constant function. But $u$ is not constant, so this is a contradiction.